# Changing between privacy type of profile attributes

Tags: mobile, web-app, mobile-web, settings, profile

The privacy settings page will list all the user profile attributes like Name, Age, School, Work, Hobbies, Contact Info etc. sans their values. The user can then choose which of the attributes to make **Public**, **Private** or **Confidential**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA4lMz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

While in *Read Only mode*, the user can see the list of all the attributes categorized according to their privacy settings.

However, I'm unsure of the *Edit mode* layout. One of the thoughts is to have a drop down with the three privacy setting values. When the dropdown changes (to say Private), a checkbox (or radio) appears to the right of attributes in other categories. The user can then check the attributes and press Submit to make the selected attributes as say Private.

Generally, had there been only two choices, a toggle switch would have been a better idea. How do I handle the three choices?
Is there a better way to allow changing (or editing) the privacy settings of individual attributes?

Please edit the tags if inappropriate.

UPDATE:
The attributes could number in hundreds

Answer (score 1):

With your approach - wouldnt this mean, that every time I view the read-only mode, the sequence of items might be different?

If I had salary as confidential yesterday, and have it public today- rather than appearing in the first box, it will now appear in the last box.

Every time i make a change, I will have to go through a learning, to know where the fields moved.

I would rather have the  read only list in a static sequence.

The other thought - why not have the Edit Section in a check box manner.

Have an initial selection of Private, Confidential, Etc. On clicking any, the user gets a check box list of all the fields, and he can choose all that he wants to fall in that category

Sorry for the ugly mocks, but this might work
[image]

Comment: Nice point regarding the order of items. I do not quite visualise your solution for the edit section. Do you mean to have the Private, Confidential etc checkboxes in the same row as that of an attribute for each of them? If yes, it'd take up too much width for a mobile screen.

Comment: I am sorry, I realized I didnt explain it in enough detail

So your privacy screen might look slightly different from your read-only screen.

The user sees three accordions (vertical or horizontal). 
He chooses any one (lets say public)

Comment: Once he does that, he gets to see a check box list of all the fields (Name, salary age, etc)
Each field has a check box. This means, if it is checked, that field is public and vice versa.
The fields that are already publi will be checked by default.

He can repeat the same for Private, Confidential

Comment: Wouldn't that be a redundant listing of all the attributes? They can run in hundreds

Comment: Yep it would. I thought your list was limited to the fields mentioned in your screens.
In that case, I would have a static sequence of fields, with an icon/tag indicating the current Privacy setting

In the edit mode, 
1. there appears a check box against each field
2. The tags/icons mentioned above are still visible
3. a drop down at the top of the check boxes
4. Drop down allows him to "make Private/Public/Confidential"
5 After (un)checking the desired fields, he chooses an option from the drop down.

Comment: I don't seem to understand how this differs from the current implementation. There are checkboxes against each field; there is the dropdown above the checkboxes, the dropdown allows to change the privacy.

Comment: Just the static sequence of events. No other difference.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

If the table is not an option then I suggest editing each field individually, instead of per group, to avoid confussion. (Radio buttons might work better here but they would occupy more width)

[image: individually]

---

**Original**

Why not display all the information in the same view without the need to click the dropdown?

[image: table]

This table could work for both Edit and Read only.

Comment: Would take up considerable width in mobile screens

Comment: I edited the answer

Comment: The new solution has too much movements. Tap a dropdown, scroll to select the value. Repeat for every attribute.